# Angular: how to export server generated file to CSV on client side?

Tags: python-3.x, angular

The following Angular code exports an empty csv file due to response.body being undefined

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileDownloadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  download_adhoc_report(endpoint, params, url, report_name = 'data.csv') {
    const httpOptions = {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer' as 'json',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      params: new HttpParams()
    };
    if (params) {
      httpOptions.params = new HttpParams();
      for (let k in params) {
        httpOptions.params = httpOptions.params.set(k, params[k]);
      }
    }
    

//    ISSUE COMES HERE


    this.http.get(url + endpoint, httpOptions).subscribe((response: HttpResponse<ArrayBuffer>) => {
      const blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'text/csv' }); //HERE response.body is UNDEFINED
      saveAs(blob, report_name);
    }, error => {
      console.error('File download failed:', error);
    });
  }
}
```

The console.log(response) returns:

[image]

Server-side code:

```
import azure.functions as func
from ..shared import blobOps

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    
    report_path = req.params.get('output_filePath') + req.params.get('output_fileName')

    try:
        
        with open(req.params["LOCALFILENAME"], "r") as my_blob2:
           file = my_blob2.read()
       
        headers = {
                "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=data.csv",
                "Content-Type": "text/csv"
            }
        
        return func.HttpResponse(file, headers=headers, status_code=200)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return func.HttpResponse("Error : File not found", status_code=404)
```

The response from the server is not empty (and seems to contain the desired data) so my guess is that the issue is in the response type or the way it is being read.

Would much appreciate any hints on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

To download the file as csv I would use the following work arround:

```
 `
     download_adhoc_report(endpoint, params, url, report_name = 'data.csv') {
       return this.httpClient
            .get(endpoint, {
                headers,
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                params: params,
            })
            .subscribe((response) =>
                this.downloadFile(
                    response,
                    `text/csv`,
                    report_name
                )
            ); 
    }
      downloadFile(data: any, type: string, filename: string) {
            let blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = window.document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }
    `
```

the downloadFile method will create a tag element with download link which was created using the [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) method and simulate a click event on it

Comment: thanks but I don't think this adresses the issue since it just replaces usage of file-saver dependency with plain vanilla javascript. as per my original post, the issue is that response.body is undefined